# Storing java Class object in a Hashmap<String, Superclass> with subclasses

Tags: java, hashmap, subclass

```
private final HashMap<String, Class<crawler.jobs.Worker>> availableWorkers = new HashMap<>();


availableWorkers.put("locations", LocationWorker.class);
availableWorkers.put("events", EventWorker.class);

 Class<crawler.jobs.Worker> workerClass = availableWorkers.get(queue);
```

LocationWorker and EventWorker both implement Worker

I want to store the Worker classes in an Hashmap. But this approach doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Class<? extends crawler.jobs.Worker>` instead, in both the `Map` declaration and the thing you're getting out.  There is only one object in the entire program which can possibly match `Class<crawler.jobs.Worker>`, and it is `crawler.jobs.Worker.class`.